# Quick way to toggle between "Larger Text", "Default", and "More Space" on Macbook Retina

Tags: macos, keyboard, display, shortcut

On Macbook's with retina display you are able to select between 4 different scale modes as showed in the picture below

[image: The different display scale modes]

It takes some clicks to get into the Display settings and choosing a new scale. I guess I am not the only one changing the scale frequently so I am confident that an easier solution to this exists.

**Question:**
Are there any keyboard shortcuts that toggles the different scale modes without the need of third party software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Automator to script things like that since OS X does't include a built in command key for that option. Once it's scripted, you can then assign a key shortcut to that script/action.

Open automator and search for the "watch me do" action for scripting of the UI.

Relevant tutorials are at https://macosxautomation.com/automator/foo.html

Comment: So no :( I was hoping to avoid any other software. Instead it should be as if you were changing the volume on the function buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/). You can easily switch resolutions from the menu bar instead of going through the `Settings.app` and you can set hotkeys for predefined resolutions/configurations as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]